# Angular App - rewrite issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to remove # from angular app

1. I have 2 views (index.html and page1.html) in an angular application hosted on apache server
2. Created alias (apps-demo) pointing to the folder where the files are placed

url will be : https://servername/apps-demo
when i navigate to page1 it will be : https://servername/apps-demo/Page1
but when i reload page i get 404 not found
i have tried writing rewrite rule in .htaccess , ssl.conf (inside virtualhost)

[index.html](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/16396398/16801266/537fffe4-4917-11e6-87a3-ec7283ef81f9.png)

Comment: use without html5mode true.

Comment: i have to remove # from the application.  i can do that only if i can set html5Mode as true

Answer (score 0):

Write a rule in web.config after `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` is set in `app.js`.

Hope, it helps.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

In my index.html I added this to

```
<base href="/">
```

Don't forget to install url rewriter for iis on server.

Also if you use Web Api and IIS, this match url will not work out, as it will change your api calls. So add third input(third line of condition) and give out a pattern that will exclude calls from www.yourdomain.com/api

For apache this link may help [enter link description here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)

Comment: this works in windows when we are hosting it on iis. i am aware of this, i need the same in apache server

Comment: did you see the link, it explain for apache?